# Why does .html work with $(x) but not with x?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
var zoomPopup = document.getElementById('image-zoom');
zoomPopup.hide();
```

some other code

```
$('#container').find('.zoomImage').on('click', function () {
        zoomPopup.show();
        $(zoomPopup).html('<img src="/static/on.png" height="64px" width="64px">');
        console.log('adres: ' +  this.src);
});
```

If I try to write it without `$()`:

```
zoomPopup.html('<img src="/static/on.png" height="64px" width="64px">');
```

I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: zoomPopup.html is not a function

Why is it? And why does `zoomPopup.show()` work ok?

Comment: zoomPopup.html() will not work, and in normaly case zoomPopup.hide() or show() are not working too. Because it is not a javascript functions, for example: this is a js function document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";  ---  OR for your case zoomPopup.innerHTML ('<img src="/static/on.png" height="64px" width="64px">');

Answer (score 2):

Because you are mixing between jQuery and pure javascript. You can use only jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var zoomPopup = $('#image-zoom');
    zoomPopup.hide();

    $('#container').find('.zoomImage').on('click', function () {
        zoomPopup.html('<img src="/static/on.png" height="64px" width="64px">').show();
        console.log('adres: ' +  $(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

I'm pretty sure `zoomPopup.show()` is not working, as well as the `.hide()` method, as they not being methods for a DOM element. As the element never hides you think the `show` method works but is not.

Comment: Weird this is .hide does work as well as .show() It is a full page popup with white background so when I comment out zoomPopup.hide() I can see it.

Comment: Try to comment `zoomPopup.show()`.. if you still see the element then is clear that `.hide()` method is not working.. also.. the console should notice that those 2 methods does not exists for the object